# How do you identify a default constructor?

Tags: c#, oop

I am new to OOP.

I have read that "the constructor which takes no arguments is called the default constructor".

Is the below constructor a default constructor?

```
Class A
{
  int a;
  string b;

  public A()
  {
    a=10;
    b="Test";
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes.[‍](http://www.google.com)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is, since it doesn't have any parameters/arguments.

An example of a non-default constructor would be:

```
public A(int a)
{
   this.a = a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...So it is NOT necessary that default constructor has to set the members to default values (a=0 and b= null) ?

Comment: @Alvin: Yes, that is correct.  As the others mention, the constructor is only called the "default" constructor because the compiler will insert an empty parameterless constructor by *default* if there are no constructors explicitly written in your code.

Comment: No it is not required that you set your instance variables within the default constructor but it is good practice to do so. I recommend that you always set your instance variables in a constructor, unless you intend to use lazy initialization in a property or something.

Comment: @Kevin: When you say "set your instance variables", are you referring to their default values (0, null, etc) or non-default values?

Comment: @Zach They are just saying it is good practice to set the variables to something. You do not need to set them to the types default value.

Comment: @Zach: when I say "set your instance variables " I just mean set them to an appropriate beginning state for your application. For example, maybe you have your previousStreetAddress variable be set to "N/A" in your constructor. You don't typically set all variables to their default values in a constructor because they're automatically initialized to their default values before the constructor is called.

Comment: @Kevin: right, I agree. :) I just wanted to make sure what you were saying was clear for Alvin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is the default constructor and if you dont implement it in your code c# compiler will inject in class automatically check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691142%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to [C# 4 specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx):

> **10.11.4 Default constructors**
>   If a class contains no instance constructor declarations, a default instance constructor is
>   automatically provided. That default constructor simply invokes the
>   parameterless constructor of the direct base class.

and, for value types:

> **4.1.2 Default constructors** All value types implicitly declare a public parameterless instance constructor called the default constructor. The
>   default constructor returns a zero-initialized instance known as the
>   default value for the value type

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is a public default constructor in C# (and Java). If you do not explicitly declare one, the compiler will make an empty default constructor for you. However, if you declare a constructor with parameters, but not a default (parameterless) one, then the compiler will not automatically generate a default constructor for you.

Answer (score -1):

No, this is not the default constructor. A default constructor is the one which is called automatically when you create an instance of a class which has no constructor definition. As soon as you define a constructor with zero arguments, you override the default constructor with your custom constructor. And that's what you are doing above.

To understand this, delete your constructor and set the values of class variable a and b to 10 and "pankaj" respectively.

And then create the class instance `A defaultConst = new A();` and access the values for a and  b.

Comment: A parameterless constructor is still generally called the default constructor even if you override the automatically generated one.

Comment: @Pankaj:Thanks!!  Now I got a and b to be 10 and "pankaj", means default constructor has set the values of members what I have set rather than a=0 or b=null. Ultimately I want to say is that I found in types of constructors--default, parameterized, private, static....so the above overridden should lie in category of DEFAULT?(nothing called as custom constructor)

Comment: @BitOff : You can check the sources and understand yourself what it means when we use the word "Default". What i have answered is the most correct of all the above provided answers

Comment: @Alvin , yes you can call it a custom-default constructor but not the default constructor.